# Intellij Global Search only Returns Results from Java Files

Tags: intellij-idea

My Intellij searches only return results from .java files. Do I have to index the files myself or seomthing for searches? Any response is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The search does not process files with no assigned file type. What's the type of the files for which you expect to see results but don't see any?

Comment: really mostly just my pom files (so .xml)

Comment: This should work with no extra configuration. Please make sure that you don't have anything selected in the "File mask" field in the Find in Path dialog.

Comment: ok, the problem I am having is when I am using the shift-shift search and the cntrl-shift-alt-n. I was not using the "find in path" search (cntl-shift-f). I was not aware of that search type. That is more helpful, so you have given me a way to address my problem. Still, I would have expected to get this to work with (cntrl-shift-alt-n) searches with the filter applied.

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-Shift-N is "Goto symbol", it can't be used to search for arbitrary text. It searches specifically for names of declarations (classses, methods and fields). pom.xml files do not contain anything that can be seen as declarations, so it doesn't allow navigating to those.

Comment: thanks yole. All very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using shift-shift and ctrl-alt-shlft-n for golbal searches. Can't use them for that. As commenter here indicated, those are for names of declarations. I switched to ctrl-shift-f for "find in path" searches. That works for arbitrary text across the file-types I needed.